# Removing duplicate entries in a hash of hash

Tags: ruby

Can you please give me a solution to below:

```
hash_list = {
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
```

**Expected output:** Duplication in all fields should be removed

```
{
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
```

Comment: Which key is removed? Why is "b" removed and not "a"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
hash_list = {
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
hash_list.to_a
         .uniq { |_, hash| hash.values_at('unit_id', 'dep_id', '_destroy') }
         .to_h
# => {"a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

Note: If the inner hash has only the keys shown in post, then `Hash#values` is enough.

Comment: But what if the keys are different?

Comment: @JikkuJose Don't assume. I answered as per the _data_ given by the OP. That's OP's responsibility.. Anyway I fixed. But there can be multiple things, which is impossible to assume. We answer based on what we see in the post.

Comment: Okay, yes! Shouldn't be assuming and should solve for the minimum requirement.

Comment: @JikkuJose See another answer... How would you control there? That's how people think here. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
hash_list.invert.invert
```

[Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-invert) creates a new hash where the values of the old hash are the keys of the new hash, which will remove any duplicate values of the old hash. The second call to `invert` swaps back round.

This doesn't give you any control over which of the keys for the duplicate values is removed though.

Answer (score 0):

One could also write the following, but Frederick's solution is clearly the one to use:

```
Hash[hash_list.group_by { |_,v| v }.map { |_,v| v.first }]
  #=> {"a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  #    "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  #    "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

For Ruby 1.9+ this will keep the first key-value pair `k=>v` among all key-value pairs with value `v`.