# Removing duplicate entries in a hash of hash with different hash values

Tags: ruby, hash

```
hash_list = {
 "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
 "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
 "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
 "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"5"}
}
```

I am expecting the result as below,

```
{
 "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
 "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"5"}
}
```

How can I get the above result? If I do

```
hash_list.invert.invert
```

then, I get

```
{
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"5"}
}
```

In the above result, `"b"` is actually not needed. I need to maintain the value with the id.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916171.

Comment: I think the question is relatively clear, he has a general description of what should happen, example input, expected output, what he tried, and what's wrong with the result of his attempt.  I've edited it to try to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Your comment in the edit is nonsense. How are the values of `"a"` and `"b"` the same as that of `"c"`? What is the logic that is "relatively clear" to you? Can you spell it out?

Comment: The OP is clear, just mistaken.  It's not the same as nonsense.  You should look up what the word "nonsense" means.

Comment: @jissy "a", "b" and "c" are not duplicates of each other.  "a" and "b" are the same, but "c" is different because it has a different `dep_id`.  That's why "b" and "c" both show up when you do `hash_list.invert.invert`.  In other words, your code is correct, it's your assumption that "a", "b", and "c" are duplicates of one another that is incorrect.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta What is mistaken? It is not clear at all. You should look up what the word "same" means.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Your last comment above contradicts with your edit. I will ask again: How are the values of `"a"` and `"b"` the same as that of `"c"`? Can you spell it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68856/discussion-between-amit-kumar-gupta-and-sawa).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate entries in a hash of hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916171/removing-duplicate-entries-in-a-hash-of-hash)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.Please read fully & if possible, please help.

Comment: I rollback the change to Revision #2. Amit did too much and it makes confused.

Comment: Is the interpretation of your question that I give in my answer correct? Regardless, I thought the problem I addressed was an interesting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I define hash `g` to be *dominated* by hash `h` if and only if `g[k] == h[k]` for all keys in `g` (i.e., for all `k` in `g.keys`). Further, I define a key-value pair `k=>h` in `hash_list` to be *dominated* if there is another key-value pair `kk=>hh` such that the hash `h` is dominated by the hash `hh`.

I have assumed that a hash is to be returned that contains only non-dominated key-value pairs from `hash_list`. With this definition:

- `a` is removed because it is dominated by `b` (and `d`) and
- `b` is removed because it is dominated by `d`.

**Code**

```
def remove_dominated_values(hash)
  hl = hash.dup
  keys = hl.keys
  key = keys.shift
  while keys.any?
    h = hl[key]
    hkeys, hvalues = hl[key].keys, hl[key].values
    hl.delete(key) if keys.any? { |k| hvalues == hl[k].values_at(*hkeys) }
    key = keys.shift
  end
  hl
end
```

**Example**

```
hash_list = {
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"5"}
}

remove_dominated_values(hash_list)
  #=> {"c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  #    "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"5"}}
```

Comment: I like this answer with full explanation.